# How can i decouple my model's data source from PHP ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, decoupling

The situation: All our app's models are coupled to the ActiveRecord framework, and inherit from ActiveRecord\Model. The problem is that we are moving some of our data to a REST service and thus a handful of our models will no longer be accessing the database our ActiveRecord framework is configured to.

A part of me wants to create an interface and use dependency injection to assign a data source to the models I need to rewire. However, things are never that easy. ActiveRecord models are strongly coupled to the other ActiveRecord models vis-a-vis has_many, has_one, and belongs_to relationships, and I'm not sure how that would work.

Has anyone successfully done this that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please show a few snippets of your code so that responders can refer to specific entities in their answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried on a few occasions, but then decided it was a lost cause just due to the architecture of php-ar and wrote my own Data Mapper infrastructure. I would imagine you will come to the same conclusion at some point.

Comment: Is this posted to any public repo I might be able to take a look at? I'm interested. Thanks for the response.